# Public path issue with webpack chunk name dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Im importing the vue app if a specific class name exists. So basically its dynamically importing. Below is the code for webpackChunk. In home.js file I check if element exists and dynamically load it.

```
if (elementExists) { import(/* webpackChunkName: "vue" */ '../vue/main.js') }
```

In the production build, I get vue.js and vendor~vue.js which is refered in the home.js file for dynamically loading it in production build. But the path for these 2 files gives me 404 error. So basically the path seems to be an issue. In webpack config I have specified the chunkFileName as

```
chunkFilename: 'scripts/[name].js',
```

Can someone suggest how to solve the path issue in prod

Comment: were you able to resolve this?